# How to remove a view controller from the flow?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have four viewController let A,B,C,D. And my flow is from A to D.I want to remove B view controller when I have reached to D. I am using present viewController to present next view.

Comment: so you would like to move back from C to A directly?

Comment: yes, i want to remove back flow C to B

Comment: @KristopherJohnson I guess its not navigation stack he is presenting instead of pushing.

Comment: @user9294044 By presenting its not possible but if you use `navigationController` then it has `viewControllers` property which is an array and you can `remove/replace/add` any `controller` to it. Even you can use custom `presenting/dismissing` animation while `pushing` and `popping`.

Comment: @user9294044 what you actually want? please elaborate more

Answer (score -1):

From your eg., In D Screen you need to check `self.navigationController?.viewControllers` and remove desired ViewController.

```
    var newArray = [UIViewController]()

    if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
        for vc in viewControllers {

            if !(vc is <#Desired ViewController#>) {
                newArray.append(vc)
            }
        }
       self.navigationController?.viewControllers = newArray
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer for this question. Please read the question carefully.